# Catching sockpuppets

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a log table containing user ids, ip addresses and log in datetimes. I need to find out who are the users who pretend to be other users by setting up multiple accounts.

This is my sample log table:

```
+---------+-------------+---------------------+
| user id | ip address  | log in datetime     |
+---------+-------------+---------------------+
| 17      | 192.168.1.4 | 2012-04-01 00:01:00 |
+---------+-------------+---------------------+
| 21      | 192.168.1.2 | 2012-04-01 00:02:00 |
+---------+-------------+---------------------+
| 11      | 192.168.1.5 | 2012-04-01 00:06:00 |
+---------+-------------+---------------------+
| 1       | 192.168.1.3 | 2012-04-01 00:09:00 |
+---------+-------------+---------------------+
| 3       | 192.168.1.3 | 2012-04-01 00:15:00 |
+---------+-------------+---------------------+
| 8       | 192.168.1.5 | 2012-04-01 00:22:00 |
+---------+-------------+---------------------+
| 9       | 192.168.1.1 | 2012-04-01 00:26:00 |
+---------+-------------+---------------------+
| 13      | 192.168.2.1 | 2012-04-01 00:27:00 |
+---------+-------------+---------------------+
| 2       | 192.168.1.1 | 2012-04-01 00:28:00 |
+---------+-------------+---------------------+
| 33      | 192.168.1.7 | 2012-04-01 00:30:00 |
+---------+-------------+---------------------+
| 27      | 192.168.1.1 | 2012-04-01 00:31:00 |
+---------+-------------+---------------------+
| 22      | 192.168.1.7 | 2012-04-01 00:45:00 |
+---------+-------------+---------------------+
```

So, here is my question: how to select a list of user ids having the same ip address and with log in time difference of less than 5 minutes?

Comment: Note that some users will share the same IP address if they are behind a NAT. This does not necessarily mean that they are sock puppets.

Comment: @MarkByers, yes, I considered that as well, that is why I am taking log in time into consideration too.

Comment: Yes; although sharing an IP _may_ indicate sock-puppetry, you might wish to add in extra metrics as well. The obvious one is sharing a cookie, which is a guarantee of multiple-accounts - although any competent sock-puppet would use two different browsers. A Flash cookie might help you there. Or, use the duplicate IP approach, but then flag it for mod attention, rather than taking an automatic action.

Comment: @BenHuh: Even taking login time into consideration, it still won't work.

Comment: @MarkByers, is there a more refine way of doing it? I wouldn't want to spend too much time to comb through the log table...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this -

```
SELECT *
FROM log l1
INNER JOIN log l2
    ON l1.ip_address = l2.ip_address
    AND l1.user_id < l2.user_id
    AND l1.login _time BETWEEN (l2.login_time - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE) AND (l2.login_time + INTERVAL 5 MINUTE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would work

```
SELECT t1.user_id,t2.user_id
FROM login_table t1
    INNER JOIN login_table t2 ON t1.ip_address=t2.ip_address AND t1.user_id!=t2.user_id
WHERE 
    t1.login_time BETWEEN 
        DATE_SUB(t2.login_time, INTERVAL 5 MINUTE) 
    AND DATE_ADD(t2.login_time, INTERVAL 5 MINUTE)
```

If you only want unique pairs and you're not bothered about the order then you could use

```
SELECT DISTINCT GREATEST(t1.user_id,t2.user_id),LEAST(t1.user_id,t2.user_id)...
```

Comment: I tried your solution, got more results than expected. There is a comma missing in your DATE_SUB and DATE_ADD

Comment: @BenHuh Thanks, added the missing commas. Why did you get more results than you expected? Was it because you got matching pairs twice (i.e. A-B and B-A)?

Comment: Not just that, I get results that are outside the 5 minute time interval as well

Comment: @BenHuh Can you give an example of some incorrect data this query is returning?

Comment: Your solution works too. I see wrongly, it is within the 5 minute interval. But nnichols got it without the duplicates. Thanks for your help too :)

Comment: I think inner join may be memory intensive if I have a big log table. I think there should be a two step solution as well.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9773/discussion-between-liquorvicar-and-ben-huh)